# Is it possible that Magento doesn't transform my optimized images?

Tags: image, optimization, caching

a graphic designer optimizes the images (products, galleries,...) for me, with good proportion of quality and compression,… and then Magento creates new images,… that are double size and not same quality. In example, 3 optimized images with sizes 392K, 428K, 281K, Magento create new ones to cache folder, and what I get at frontend are this new images: 642K, 738K, 504K.

So, my question is How can I solve this? It has no sense to have a graphic designer, and then Magento overwrite his work,...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento rebuild his own images cache with different image sizes.

This behaviour allows template designer to get product images in the format they need.

You have different options to workaround your problem:

**Option 1: Change image quality**

In your phtml files you will find something like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265) ?>" />
```

Just try modifying the default quality level with:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->setQuality(95)->resize(265) ?>" />
```

**Option 2: Directly show the original image file**

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()) ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I'd like to show the original image, as it has been optimized by a graphic designer. Has it any disadvantage to directly show the original image, instead of the Magento chache rebuilded image?

I want this when I show the gallery images of the product. So now I have this line, inside the foreach: $img_src=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); 

so, what I need to change to show the original image of the gallery? Sorry, but I'm new with Magento...

Comment: It depends on your template. I do not see any side effect. I just suggest you to avoid using original images for thumbnails.

Comment: So, just to confirm, with the foreach I have, this is correct?: 
foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image): 
 $img_original = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_image->getFile());

Comment: AFAIK it should work.